# How to create one array of char from different variable(data type) in one line?

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to create array of char from different data types merging it into one char array.  `char array[32] = "matrix"+a+b+".txt";` E.g:

```
int main(){
int a = 10;
int b = 10;

char array[32] = "matrix"+a+b+".txt";
return 0;
}
```

I have tried different ways. But it didn't helped. Thank you!

Comment: C or C++. Pick one, the answer is different for each.

Comment: C or C++? Different languages, different answers.

Comment: It is better for c. Also, it will be great if you will give for c++.

Comment: In c++ [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) will do that for you. It overloads `operator+`. See [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) for converting `int` to `std::string`.

Comment: Is there way to do it in c? @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: @JasurbekNabijonov This is why everyone wants you to specify 1 language. The solutions aren't remotely similar. You are asking two different questions in the same post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C, use [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

```
int a = 10;
int b = 10;

char array[32];

snprintf(array, sizeof(array), "matrix%d%d.txt", a, b);
```

For C++, use strings instead of character arrays; you can concatenate strings easily since they overload the `+` operator:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 10;

std::string str{std::string{"matrix"} + std::to_string(a) + std::to_string(b) + ".txt"};
```

Comment: Wow! It works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should firstly understand how a **C-string** works... a C-String is always an array of chars... but an array of char is **not always** a C-String.

The "definition" (not a formal definition, but something close to it) is that a C-String contains a sequence of bytes that will represent a string (characters) and the end of the string will be marked with a null-byte (0)

This is a C-String:

```
char myString[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 };
```

This is **NOT** a C-String:

```
char myBuffer[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

Checking your example... trying to make `"matrix"+a+b+".txt"` shows that you are actually looking for construct a **C-String** with different types.

--

So, in order to mix different types of data in order to build a string we have several options...

- In C: use `snprintf()`
- In C++: use `std:string` or `std::ostringstream`

There are more options for both, but these above are very common.

The `std::string` in C++ is NOT a C-String... but can be converted to one with the function `.c_str()`.